# Mouseup events are not working inside Swiper

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I'm using Swiper to show some slides, and I have some events that run on `mouseup`, but they are not working with Swiper. When I click the swiper container nothing happens.

You can see it in this example, the alert doesn't work:

```js
document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', () => { alert('mouseup'); });

const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  direction: 'horizontal',
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
  },
});
```

```css
.swiper-container {
  width: 80vw;
  height: 80vh;
}

html, body {
width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#m {
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.3.2/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.3.2/js/swiper.min.js"></script>

<div id="m">
<div class="swiper-container">
    <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <!-- Slides -->
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
        ...
    </div>
    <!-- If we need pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

    <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

    <!-- If we need scrollbar -->
    <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

I think it does it to avoid events interfering with the Swipe, but if the user doesn't swipe, just clicks, I would like to trigger my events.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swiper does that on purpose to avoid events from messing up the swipe. One way to change this behavior is to trick it to think that your elements are form elements. Internally it does a check and if the target is a form element it allows the click.

You can change `Swiper`s `init` function to set the form elements data:

```
const i = Swiper.prototype.init;
Swiper.prototype.init = function () {
  this.touchEventsData.formElements = '*';
  i.call(this);
};
```

[image: prevent default]

With that it will no longer lock `mouseup` events.

The following example shows an event with `alert`, it works but causes ux problems with the swiping.

```js
document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', () => { alert('mouseup'); });

const i = Swiper.prototype.init;
Swiper.prototype.init = function () {
  this.touchEventsData.formElements = '*';
  i.call(this);
};

const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  direction: 'horizontal',
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
  },
});
```

```css
.swiper-container {
  width: 80vw;
  height: 80vh;
}

html, body {
width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#m {
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.3.2/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.3.2/js/swiper.min.js"></script>

<div id="m">
<div class="swiper-container">
    <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <!-- Slides -->
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
        ...
    </div>
    <!-- If we need pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

    <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

    <!-- If we need scrollbar -->
    <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

For me, just adding this `touchStartPreventDefault: false` on Swiper options solved my issues with "mousedown" and "mouseup".

Comment: Thank you! In my case I needed a draggable/sortable list within each swiper slide. But the swiper parent was blocking any mousedown/drag events on children (assuming it was to do with swipers own drag/swipe events).

Comment: Doesn't work nicely if u have images in your slides.
It just drags the image (just like how an image should behave by default) and:
1. Changes your mouse cursor (shows that you're dragging the image), not cool.
2. Sometimes changing slides gets stuck and you're changing the slide to the next one, even though you're not holding down the mouse button, kinda weird.

Comment: It worked great for me in a situation where the swiper's children were not getting click events.

Answer (score 4):

Update Swiper and add `touchStartPreventDefault: false` in swiper options

```js
document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', () => { alert('mouseup'); });

const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  direction: 'horizontal',
  touchStartPreventDefault: false,
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
  },
});
```

```css
.swiper-container {
  width: 80vw;
  height: 80vh;
}

html, body {
width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#m {
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<div id="m">
<div class="swiper-container">
    <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <!-- Slides -->
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
        ...
    </div>
    <!-- If we need pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

    <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

    <!-- If we need scrollbar -->
    <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
</div>
</div>
```